# Keyboard shortcut to go to last tab in Opera on Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

If there are more than 10 tabs open in Opera, how do I directly jump to the last tab?

In Chrome, this was doable via <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>, but in Opera, this takes me to the 9th tab.

Comment: Went through the keyboard shortcuts, there is no option to do that. At least in the latest version. You can try some addons that show the tabs as a list on your sidebar

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following workaround:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

Mac (I'm guessing): <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>

The first bit switches to the first tab, the second bit does a "switch left through tabs". If you've checked the the "Enable advanced keyboard shortcuts" option (Settings > Browser > Shortcuts), then you can replace the second bit with just <kbd>1</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

If you want more customisability (closer to how Opera used to be before switching to Blink, i.e. 12.x and earlier), try [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) (which also still has the ability to switch to the last tab rather than the 9th one).